# how to hide status bar in ios from a current VC when presenting another VC modally?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, statusbar

How would I go about hiding a status bar from the current VC right before I present another VC modally?

I don't want to change it through the entire app, just when I'm about to present another vc then when I come back to the first VC I want the status bar to come back.

what I've tried:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `setStatusBarHidden`. Implement `prefersStatusBarHidden` appropriately in each view controller.

Comment: but i want it to show but i dont want it to show when presenting the modal

Comment: when i call `prefersStatusBarHidden Bool` it makes it hidden all the time. I want to be able to make it hidden and make it show

Comment: You are not doing what I said. "_Appropriately_ in _each view controller_."

Comment: I dont think you understand, I would like to be able to toggle hidden on and off.

Comment: @Prgmmr In the modal view controller, return `YES` from `prefersStatusBarHidden`. In every other view controller, return `NO`.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.